# Python - Only continue main function once threads have executed?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python function that does something like this (very rough pseudocode):

```
while True:

    set_up_some_variables()

    start_4_threads() 

    continue_computing()
```

The "continue_computing" task depends on the outputs of the intense threaded task. How do I make sure that it only executes once the threads have all completed?

I've thought about using a locks (i.e. before the threads start, 4 locks are acquired and are released once the thread finishes) - but this doesn't allow me to be flexible with the number of threads. Also, it doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Comment: `thread.join()`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: `thread.join()` will do it for sure and it's the most elegant soln.
But if you want a twisted soln, I suggest Semaphores and spin locking in main thread (A twisted one and probably bad for performance) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) waits for all threads to reach a point in the program before continuing.

```
def foo(id, var):
    print(id, var)

# Set up some variables
vars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Start threads
for id in range(4):
    thread.start_new_thread(foo, (id, vars[id]))

# Wait for all threads to run foo before continuing
thread.join()

print("All threads complete!")
```